# Google Cloud Text to speech not returning timepoints?

Tags: python, google-text-to-speech

As in the the title. I am attempting to convert some ssml,

```
<speak><mark name="0"/>The Antikythera Mechanism is an ancient device shrouded in mystery. Discovered in 1901 off the Greek island Antikythera, sponge divers found a shipwreck hiding this enigmatic relic. For centuries, its secrets lay dormant beneath the waves, waiting for the day they would resurface and amaze the world.<mark name="1"/>Retrieved from the depths, it appeared as a lump of corroded bronze and wood. Initial appearances were deceiving within this unassuming artifact was a window into the advanced technological prowess of ancient civilizations, ready to challenge and expand our understanding of history.<mark name="2"/>Careful cleaning and examination revealed gears, inscriptions, and signs of complex inner mechanisms. The Antikythera Mechanisms design was intricate. With every gear and turning dial, the evidence mounted that ancient civilizations were capable of mechanical engineering far beyond what had been imagined.<mark name="3"/>Rewind to Ancient Greece, over 2,000 years ago. Greek scholars, under a canopy of stars, pursued the mysteries of the cosmos. Astronomy was paramount it was not only a science but also a spiritual connection, an attempt to decode existence through celestial observation.<mark name="4"/>Greek culture was steeped in celestial symbolism. Temples were dedicated to gods who ruled the heavens. Festivals aligned with lunar and solar events. Understanding celestial movements was essential, as the stars and planets were not just celestial bodies, but guides for life.<mark name="5"/>Inside an ancient workshop, brilliant craftsmen aimed to create a device to simulate the cosmos. Combining knowledge and resources, they fashioned what is now known as the Antikythera Mechanism, a complex assembly of gears and dials meant to represent the celestial world.<mark name="6"/>This shoebox-sized device contained at least 30 gears. When the handle turned, the gears moved, displaying the Moon, Sun, and planets positions on any selected date. The mechanism was a marvel, an ancestor to the computers we use today.<mark name="7"/>Additionally, the Mechanism had calendar dials, predicting solar and lunar eclipses. The versatility and complexity of this ancient device suggest that Greek technology was advanced, with an understanding of astronomical events and cycles that rivaled modern knowledge.<mark name="8"/>The Antikythera Mechanism likely traversed the Mediterranean on ancient trade routes. The identity of its creator and its intended recipient remains unknown, but it is believed that the ship carrying it was bound for Rome.<mark name="9"/>Suddenly, a storm brewed, waves clashed against the ship, and with a timber crack, it sank. The Antikythera Mechanism descended into the depths, forgotten for centuries as it rested on the seabed, cocooned in its watery grave.<mark name="10"/>As centuries turned to millennia, the world changed. Empires rose and fell, and the sands of time buried memories of the Mechanism. It seemed destined to remain a lost treasure, hidden from human eyes.<mark name="11"/>Fast forward to 1901. Divers exploring the Antikythera coast discovered the shipwreck. Among an array of ancient treasures, they found the Mechanism. Initially unrecognized, this corroded artifact was about to change our understanding of history.<mark name="12"/>The National Archaeological Museum in Athens became its home. Visitors and scholars gazed upon this relic, unaware of its true significance. Curiosity grew, and the quest to unveil the Mechanisms secrets began.<mark name="13"/>Utilizing X-ray imaging, 3D modeling, and various tools, scientists and historians delved into its inner workings. Each examination revealed more gears, more complexity, and evidence of an astonishing understanding of the cosmos.<mark name="14"/>This device, with its precise arrangement of gears, represented the cosmos. Its believed to be the first analog computer. The Antikythera Mechanism was a marvel of ancient engineering, a testament to the boundless capabilities of the human mind.<mark name="15"/>Its not just gears and dials its a reflection of the Greek cosmos. A map of the stars, the paths of the planets, an orchestra of celestial motion. Through this device, we see how the ancient Greeks viewed the universe.<mark name="16"/>Picture an ancient scholar, dialing in a date, observing the movements of celestial bodies. Imagine the wonder as the dials and pointers moved in tandem with the heavens. It was like holding the universe in ones hands.<mark name="17"/>It may have been used for astronomy, navigation, or calendrical calculations. Additionally, it may have served educational or philosophical purposes. This versatility highlights the Mechanisms central role in ancient Greek society and intellectual life.</speak>
```

However no timepoints are returned.

I am using the python client library for v1beta1. This is the function that has the ssml above passed into it. In the responce object the timepoints array will simply be empty. I was orginally using a nueral2 voice, but saw some hints that nueral2 may not support timepoints properly?

```
def synthesize_voice(ssml_text):
    """Synthesize text to mp3 using Google Text-to-Speech API"""
    client = texttospeech_v1beta1.TextToSpeechClient()

    input_text = texttospeech_v1beta1.SynthesisInput(ssml=ssml_text)

    voice = texttospeech_v1beta1.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code="en-US",
        name="en-US-News-M")


    audio_config = texttospeech_v1beta1.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=texttospeech_v1beta1.AudioEncoding.MP3,
    )

    request = texttospeech_v1beta1.SynthesizeSpeechRequest(input=input_text, voice=voice,audio_config =audio_config, enable_time_pointing=[texttospeech_v1beta1.SynthesizeSpeechRequest.TimepointType.SSML_MARK])

    response = client.synthesize_speech(request)
```

Any idea why response.timepoints would come back empty despite the obvious presence of marks?